# How to map absolute values on either side of zero to a linear 0->100% value?

Tags: python, scaling, adc, range-map

I've got a bit of a unique problem with a raspberry pi pico (or maybe I just don't know the right terms to search). I have an analog sensor on an accelerator pedal for a simulator I'm putting together. The values I'm getting back are going from 65535->0->65535, rather than ***-***65535->0->65535, which is essentially giving me an absolute value to work with, even though the pedal is being pressed down continually. So using a range map function where I map a min and max to some other min and max (e.g. 0->65535 || 0->100%) doesn't work because my min and max have the same value (hopefully the photo shows a bit better/more graphically the issue I'm seeing)

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set a flag when I'm in a dead band (say value <= 20) as I pass by that dead band, then keep track of the direction I'm coming from and going toward in order to make it act like my desired "0->100%", linear value. Where I'm getting stuck is that I've got to keep track of when I pass it in the would-be positive direction to set the flag, then again on the would-be negative direction to remove the flag. I can't seem to find a concise way to do it and I feel that I'm probably over-thinking it. That or it's not possible to do without some other reference to go from (like an indicator if you're in the left half of the range or the right half).

Here's the python code I have so far. I am trying to map this to a range of -127 to 127 for an analog trigger for an emulated game pad, returning a value that either has a max/min or a min/max (flipping the value's sign, essentially) based on which side of the dead zone it's on. I'm eager to hear your thoughts! Thanks!

```
def getScaledAcceleratorPosition():
        # Establish a few basic values we need to evaluate
        acceleratorValue = analog_activePins[0].value
        posDifference = (last_AcceleratorVal - acceleratorValue)
        
        if (digital_activePins[9].value == False) and (digital_activePins[10].value == False): #If neither butterfly switch is enabled, then return 127 for the position of the accelerator
            global last_AcceleratorVal = 65535
            global sawAccelDeadBand = False     # Reset memory on seeing the deadband in the middle of accelerator pedal travel
            global pedalMovingDown = False
            global pedalMovingUp = True
            return -127 # Send fully retracted position for analog Right Trigger
        elif (digital_activePins[9].value == True or digital_activePins[10].value == True):
            # Take care of a condition where the accelerator pedal rests at Maximum value
            if acceleratorValue > 65520 and acceleratorValue <= 65535:
                global last_AcceleratorVal = 65535
                global sawAccelDeadBand = False     # Reset memory on seeing the deadband in the middle of accelerator pedal travel
                global pedalMovingDown = False
                global pedalMovingUp = True
                return -127
                
            # Create small dead zones at the ends of travel
            if acceleratorValue >= 65520: acceleratorValue = 65530
            if acceleratorValue <= 500: acceleratorValue = 0
            if acceleratorValue > 0 and acceleratorValue <= 20: sawAccelDeadBand = True     # Set a flag when we pass the accelerator deadband in the middle of travel.
            
            # Compensate for the analog feedback device value map that looks like 65535->0->65535, rather than -65535->0->65535
            if (posDifference > 0 and sawAccelDeadBand == False) or (posDifference < 0 and sawAccelDeadBand == True):
                global pedalMovingDown = True
                global pedalMovingUp = False
                print("Accel Pedal Moving Down. Value: %s"%acceleratorValue)
            elif (posDifference > 0 and sawAccelDeadBand == True) or (posDifference < 0 and sawAccelDeadBand == False):
                global pedalMovingDown = False
                global pedalMovingUp = True
                print("Accel Pedal Moving Up.   Value: %s"%acceleratorValue")
            
            # Values if Pedal is moving Down:
            if pedalMovingDown == True and sawAccelDeadBand == True:
                retVal = range_map(acceleratorValue, 0, 65535, 0, 127)
                # sawDeadBandAndPedalMovingDown = True  # Need some memory for when I pass by the dead band and the pedal is moving down?
            elif pedalMovingDown == True and sawAccelDeadBand == False:
                retVal = range_map(acceleratorValue, 65535, 0, -127, 0)
            # Values if Pedal is moving Up:
            if pedalMovingUp == True and sawAccelDeadBand == True:
                retVal = range_map(acceleratorValue, 65535, 0, 0, 127)
                # sawDeadBandAndPedalMovingUp = True  # Need some memory for when I pass by the dead band and the pedal is moving up?
            elif pedalMovingUp == True and sawAccelDeadBand == False:
                retVal = range_map(acceleratorValue, 0, 65535, -127, 0)
            
            global last_AcceleratorVal = acceleratorValue
            return round(retVal)
        else:
            print("Something wrong in getScaledAcceleratorPosition Routine")
            return 0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. I'm not sure about the problem, but this code definitely isn't valid, e.g. `global last_AcceleratorVal = 65535`. You can [edit] to fix it. BTW, for tips, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There's also no photo here

Comment: Beside the point, but `acceleratorValue > 0 and acceleratorValue <= 20` can be simplified to `0 < acceleratorValue <= 20`.

Comment: This problem is unsolvable as stated; there's no way to "keep track of the direction I'm coming from", because the directions are indistinguishable.  I would have to guess that the sensor is simply miswired; a schematic diagram would be more useful than code, but if you're going to post that it belongs in Electronics.SE rather than here.